# removing columns with perl on tab delimited file

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove three columns with perl on a tabulated file.

Input file:

```
A B C D
```

Expected/new file:

```
A B C
```

I saw in other question how to remove only one column, the answer being:

```
perl.exe -na -e "print qq{$F[3]\n}" < input
```

How could I rewrite this to remove three columns?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about Perl at all? This isn't the place to ask for a free solution or a from-basics tutorial.

Comment: Just Google 'removing columns with perl on tab delimited file'. It's much quicker...

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
 perl.exe -na -e "print qq{@F[0..2]\n}" < input > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use perl in awk-mode:

```
$ cat -T f1
a^Ib^Ic^Id^Ie^If
a^Ib^Ic^Id^Ie^If
a^Ib^Ic^Id^Ie^If

$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'print $F[0],"\t",$F[1],"\t",$F[2]' input
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
```

or space-separated:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'print qq{@F[0..2]}' input
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

or to print the first three columns, tab-separated in awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2, $3}' input
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane "pop @F; print qq(@F)" input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (Perl v5.14+):

```
perl -lne "print s/.+\K\s+\S$//r" inFile
```